Vue.js - ref() vs. defineModel(). What's the difference?
I'm new in Vue.js world. So I do not understand difference between ref() and defineModel(). I've seen tutorials on YouTube and they say it makes it easier to communicate between parent and child components, but here's the code with ref():
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const model = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="model">
</template>

<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
import { ref } from 'vue';
const msg = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <MyComponent v-model="msg" />
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>


and the above code works exactly the same with defineModel():
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineModel } from 'vue';
const model = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="model">
</template>

<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
import { defineModel } from 'vue';
const msg = defineModel();
</script>    

<template>
  <MyComponent v-model="msg" />
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>

So what's the difference? Can you please give me the simple example to show me difference?

DefineModel() is a new macro that can provide better v-model tips.

It's described in the guide with the example provided, did you check before asking? https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#under-the-hood They are just different things, defineModel doesn't do what ref does, and vice versa

@EstusFlask yes, i checked docs, there are same info. please just answer me with example if you can and explain

@DevMis The example in the docs shows how it can be done with defineModel, this is what you already did in snippet 2. This cannot be done by replacing it with ref() like you tried in snippet 1, there will be no <h1>abc</h1> in the parent, so there cannot be such example. This statement "code works exactly the same" is incorrect. That's the difference between them

ref isn't a valid way to establish 2-way binding.
In your case when you do <MyComponent v-model="msg" /> the v-model actually do
<MyComponent modelValue="msg" @update:modelValue="v => msg = v"/>

Since you have only 1 element in the child's template due fallback attributes https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html the parent component starts listen update:modelValue on the input and thus updates msg (modelValue and @update:modelValue are like injected into <input>). So it looks like  the 2-way binding is properly established. But it isn't.
Once you add any additional element, the link is broken, since the fallback attributes don't work anymore:
<template>
  <div>Child component</div>
  <input v-model="t">
</template>

The verdict: use defineModel as a proper way to make a 2-way binding.

According to the vue document,v-model can be used on a component to implement a two-way binding, but in your case just like a one-way binding, in fact just no binding if you known the Fallthrough Attributes, the input emit a update:value to change the model ,and 'casual' to change the msg,so it likes the msg control the input,if you try to set some value to msg(not input),the input will not change at all.

Please give the example. I've set value to msg and everything works with ref():
`


`
and with defineModel():
`
`
Trying to set msg a value in your first case(without defineModel )
